# How can one download Google Public data say in csv form?

Tags: google-visualization

I have found some Google public data of interest to me.

http://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=ny_gdp_pcap_cd&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=country&idim=country:CHN&ifdim=country&tstart=-315424800000&tend=1262498400000&hl=en&dl=en&iconSize=0.5&icfg

I would like to download it so that I can create my own visualizations from it. Is this possible? I cannot merely embed the graph because I don't want the links to Google on my site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the "Data from World Bank, World Development Indicators" link at the bottom. You should see a link to download the data on that page.

Comment: That's dependent on the provider. In the case the OP provides, the link just heads to the World Bank's homepage. The correct answer is "It depends, but usually you can't."

Answer (score 2):

The data cannot be downloaded from Google Public Data, though it can be downloaded from the original site.  Source: http://support.google.com/publicdata/answer/1101239?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

There is a small box that contains a question mark on the axis labels. Click the box and click "More info". It would direct you to the raw data in table form.